# Using the jQuery Update module throws the "F is undefined" error

Tags: javascript

I am using the jQuery validate module (which is mandatory for client side validation module).

If I use that module, my existing functionality is not working well. It is throwing, "F is undefined" while using minified version or, "$.ui is not a function" with the normal version of jQuery.

I understood that version plays the problem here. How do I avoid the error message?

Comment: Please mention your version numbers for Drupal, the jQuery library, jQuery update module and other components that might be relevant.

Comment: Drupal 6.2, Jquery is 1.12.2.3 and jquery_update is 6.x-2.0-alpha1.. Hope this satisfy the needs.

Comment: That's a strange combination of version numbers. According to the [jQuery Update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update), you should have jQuery 1.3.2. Check if it installed correctly on the /admin/reports/status page. Also (even though it will probably not fix this problem) try to keep your Drupal core up-to-date for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) on every site we make.

One typical problem it has, is that it can cause problems on admin pages.  The issues for the module has a patch (http://drupal.org/node/775924#comment-3010750) that fixes the problem.  You can also edit this to use any version of jQuery you want, as long as you place the proper versions in the module folder.